# Why I can't see this test method in the Visual Studio test explorer box?

Tags: c#

I am absolutly new in **C#** (I came from Java) and I have the following problem

I have a test class (annotated with **[TestClass]**, into this test class I have 3 test methods.

I have create this test method:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void InsertNewVulnerability() {

        DataModel.VulnerabilityManager manager = new DataModel.VulnerabilityManager("DefaultConnection");

        try {
            manager.openConnection();


            DataModel.Vulnerability.VulnSmall mySmallVuln;

            mySmallVuln.VulnerabilityAlertId = 50000;
            mySmallVuln.SourceId = "TEST";
            mySmallVuln.BugTraqID = 3;
            mySmallVuln.Title = "TEST";
            mySmallVuln.StatusID = 3;
            mySmallVuln.CVE = "TEST";
            mySmallVuln.Published = new DateTime(1998, 04, 30); ;
            mySmallVuln.LastUpdated = new DateTime(2007, 11, 05);
            mySmallVuln.Remote = "TEST";
            mySmallVuln.Local = "TEST";
            mySmallVuln.Credibility = "TEST";
            mySmallVuln.Classification = "TEST";
            mySmallVuln.Availability = "TEST";
            mySmallVuln.Ease = "TEST";
            mySmallVuln.Authentication = "TEST";
            mySmallVuln.CVSS2_BaseScore = "TEST";
            mySmallVuln.CVSS2_TemporalScore = "TEST";
            mySmallVuln.CVSS2_BaseScore = "TEST";
            mySmallVuln.CVSS2_TemporalVector = "TEST";
            mySmallVuln.CVSS1_BaseScore = "TEST";
            mySmallVuln.CVSS1_TemporalScore = "TEST";
            mySmallVuln.NVD_CVSS2_BaseScore = "TEST";
            mySmallVuln.NVD_CVSS2_ComponentString = "TEST";
            mySmallVuln.ImpactRating = 3;
            mySmallVuln.Severity = 3;
            mySmallVuln.EaseofExploit = 3;
            mySmallVuln.UrgencyRating = 3;
            mySmallVuln.LastChange = "TEST";
            mySmallVuln.ShortSummary = "TEST";
            mySmallVuln.Impact = "TEST";
            mySmallVuln.TechnicalDescription = "TEST";
            mySmallVuln.AttackScenario = "TEST";
            mySmallVuln.Exploit = "TEST";
            mySmallVuln.Credit = "TEST";
            mySmallVuln.URL = "TEST";
            mySmallVuln.AlertStatusId = 3;
            mySmallVuln.Type = 3;
            mySmallVuln.DetailLevel = 3;
            mySmallVuln.Language = 3;

            manager.insert(mySmallVuln);

        }
        finally
        {

            manager.closeConnection();
        }


    }
```

The problem is that in the Visual Studio **test explorer** box I can't see this third method (I see the other 2 methods but not this last)

Why? What am I missing? How can I solve?

Comment: Could it be because there is no actual test? e.g. Assert blah

Comment: @PaulZahra I thought so too. But it actually works without asserts

Comment: Have you rebuilt the solution?